# Android ExoPlayer некорректный aspectRatio

Tags: android

На некоторых устройствах,ближе совсем к старым(слабым) наблюдаются проблемы с выставлением у ExoPlayer кодеком пропорции самого видео.
Проблема аналогичная с [этим вопросом](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/656).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например,Билайн Смарт 3 с RAM 512 МБ.
Для теста было использовано видео с ratio - 1920x1080.
Во время дебага

> MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.onOutputFormatChanged

выяснил,что кодек на входе действительно этот ratio принимает,а на выходе
height урезает в 2 раза.

Comment: возможно это такая корявая реакция на нехватку памяти\GPU для воспроизведения полного разрешения?

Comment: В любом случае, если вы достатточно хорошо разбираетесь в java, вы можете поковыряться в исходниках ExoPlayer сами, т. к. у него открытый код.